# Error con programa que evalúa qué número es mayor

Tags: php

Ando haciendo un programa que evalúa el mayor a tres números pero no me evalúa la condición y no arroja nada.

Debe de evaluar algo así:

```
20   2   20    2    20    2   2
2    20   5    20    2    2   2
5     5   2     2    2    5   2
```

Éste es el código:

```
<?php
    $num=20;
    $num2=2;
    $num3=5;


    if($num>$num2  && $num>$num3) {            
         echo "El numero mayor es";    
    }   

    if($num2>$num  && $num2>$num3){
        echo "El numero mayor es";            
    }

    if($num3>$num1 && $num3>$num2){
        echo "El numero mayor es ";                
    }

    if($num1>$num3 && $$num2>$num3)
    {
        echo "el numero mayor es ";            
    }

    if($num1>=$num1 && $num1>$num3)
    { 
        echo "el numero mayor es ";
    }
```

¿En que estoy mal?

Comment: Lo mejor es hacer un aux y vas comparando el aux con cada numero si numero es mayor lo guardas en el aux y ahí mostras el mayor.

Comment: Hola! sin entrar en el algoritmo estoy viendo errores de sintaxis como que la variable `$num1` no existe. Tampoco imprimes ningún resultado en los `echo`, por ejempo en el primer `if` deberías poner elgo así: `echo "El numero mayor es $num";`. En el cuarto `if`  tienes lo siguiente `$$num2`. Creo que debería empezar por solucionar estas cosas y si sigue sin funcionar seguir preguntando. Un saludo

Comment: Replanteate el algoritmo, porque lo que estás haciendo no es muy bueno. Como ya te han comentado hay fallos de sintaxis en el código. Y tampoco explicas bien que es lo que quieres realmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo que intentas resolverlo mediante comparaciones, se podría simplificar un poco del siguiente modo:

```
<?php
        $num = 20;
        $num2 = 20;
        $num3 = 5;


        if ( $num >= $num2 && $num >= $num3 ){
            echo "EL mayor es el $num";

        } else{
            if ( $num2 > $num3 )
                echo "EL mayor es el $num2";
            else
                echo "EL mayor es el $num3";
        }
```

La traza sería más o menos así:

Si `$num`es mayor a los otros dos, el mayor en `$num`

Si `$num`no es mayor a los otros dos y además `$num2`es mayor a `$num3`, el mayor es `$num2`

Si no se cumple ninguna de las dos condiciones anteriores, el mayor es `$num3`

Comment: si gracias solo que quero k se comparen todas las veces k  se pueda

Answer (score 2):

Esto se puede resolver con dos líneas de código (¡hasta con una si quieres!), usando [`max`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.max.php).

Se trataría de:

- Crear un array con todos los valores que quieres comparar. Pueden ser tres valores, pueden ser 50, pueden ser 12...
- Al invocar `max` enviando como parámetro ese array, te devolverá el mayor número entre ellos.

Por ejemplo:

```
$arrNumeros=array(20,2,5);
echo "El número mayor es: ".max($arrNumeros);
```

**Resultado:**

```
El número mayor es: 20
```

---

Observa este ejemplo:

```
$arrNumeros=array(20,2,5,-1,45,"100");
echo "El número mayor es: ".max($arrNumeros);
```

**Resultado:**

```
El número mayor es: 100
```

---

Aquí puedes hacer pruebas con el código:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/FKFJKG56841)**</kbd>

Como puedes ver, `max` es una función interesante. Si la vas a usar en varias partes de tu código, recomendaría que más adelante la incorpores a una clase utilitaria, adaptándola a tu uso (en cuanto a la forma en que debería devolver los resultados).

Espero te sirva.

Comment: si solo que me piden que lo resuelva con puros if no puedo usar arrays lo quieren con if gracias